# Find odd and even divs and put in containing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to solve something that should be really simple. But it's actually a bit trickier then I thought. I'm creating a Tumblr theme and I have a list with all posts in a containing div. For my layout I need two separate divs with all even and odd posts. How can I achieve such a thing with basic jquery?

```
<!-- Original -->
<div id="posts">
    <div class="post">Content odd</div>
    <div class="post">Content even</div>
    <div class="post">Content odd</div>
    <div class="post">Content even</div>
    <div class="post">Content odd</div>
    <div class="post">Content even</div>
</div>

<!-- New Situation -->
<div id="posts">
    <!-- Odd Posts -->
    <div id="col-one">
        <div class="post">Content odd</div>
        <div class="post">Content odd</div>
        <div class="post">Content odd</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Even Posts -->
    <div id="col-two">
        <div class="post">Content even</div>
        <div class="post">Content even</div>
        <div class="post">Content even</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vmdaM/ which seems to almost be the solution but it isn't

Comment: `:odd` and `:even` sub selectors and then simply `append` them where you want

Comment: Your first element is actually even since it has an index of 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily jQuery makes this fairly easy but it considers the first element to be even since it has an index of 0. With that assumption it can be written like so:

```
var $oddPosts = $('.post:odd');
var $evenPosts = $('.post:even');

$oddPosts.wrapAll('<div class="col-one"></div>');
$evenPosts.wrapAll('<div class="col-two"></div>');
```

Here is a plunker showing it working and with the correct odd, even divs labeled: http://plnkr.co/edit/q7vH3RhwqJFCjTuQhJWi?p=preview

As pointed out, this will cause the even posts to appear before the odd posts since the jQuery `wrapAll` inserts the wrapper at the first element. To remedy this it requires just a bit more work:

```
var $oddPosts = $('.post:odd');
var $evenPosts = $('.post:even');

var $oddPostsCol = $('<div class="col-1"></div>').append($oddPosts);
var $evenPostsCol = $('<div class="col-2"></div>').append($evenPosts);

$('#posts').append($oddPostsCol).append($evenPostsCol);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kbXkqWNzWPZXAGBWBBrB?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, I cloned the posts to a new div http://plnkr.co/edit/LHMaXD84KhN3YxR17JRf?p=preview ... the only "odd" thing is that the col-one and two are applied in the wrong order because of the index difference. Any ideas for that?

Comment: So you want odd posts to always be column 1 and listed first?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you're looking for:

```
oddDivs = $('div > div:nth-child(odd)');
evenDivs = $('div > div:nth-child(even)');
$('#col-one').append(oddDivs);
$('#col-two').append(evenDivs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz check this

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                var even=$('div div:even');
               even.wrapAll('<div class="col-1" ><div>')
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: What does your answer add over the accepted answer, which was authored more than 30 minutes before yours with a much better explanation?